# What is the estimated DPR for a hunter ranger?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, ranger, statistics

I was wondering what the average amount of a damage per round by a human ranger with the Hunter subclass should be at each level?
The answer should not include bonuses with magic items and should be calculated using a starting dex of 16 (including race bonus).

Fighting style: archery

Weapon: longbow

Subclass features:
Horde Breaker,
Escape the Horde,
Volley

Comment: Is there some particular end you want this for? As posed, this is quite a broad ask and it would probably be better to focus it to the actual problem. Also, is still relevant despite that, what have you tried yourself and where did it break down or similar?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135120/discussion-on-question-by-consus-how-much-damage-should-a-pc-do). Rather than leaving that discussion in these comments, it can be found (and continued) in the above chat. There are some clarification requests in there too, but as far as I can see they're dependent on a clarification of the primary goal so I think they're fine preserved in chat. Consus, if you're unsure how best to proceed, feel free to make use of the above chatroom.

Comment: I've said this before on a similar question of yours, but asking somebody to do the work for *all* of the classes is simply too tall of an ask. I am voting to close

Comment: I don't think it is feasible to quantify the averages of all possible builds, for all classes, for all levels. This question is way too broad in scope.

Comment: Please do not worry about other people benefiting from the post, or use that as the impetus to ask it. Ask *your* question about the problem *you* are facing.

Comment: Hi @Consus It would be somewhat unusual to (1) have Dex 18 already at level 1 and (2) stay at Dex 18 while leveling up. Dex adds both to your to hit and to your damage with ranged or finesse weapons, and as such it would typically be one of the things to maximize first for a Ranger build. Did you roll your Dex so you are starting with 18, and do you want to fix Dex at 18 through all levels?

Comment: What feats are you taking ? Fighting styles ? Weapon you are using ? etc... Build choices will affect DPR, you should specify that.

Answer (score 3):

[I will assume 60% chance to hit per level for simplicity.](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/2p8eva/a_look_at_bounded_accuracy/)

(Though, here is how hit chance works. If the enemy has an AC of X and you have a bonus to hit of Y, then you need to roll at least X - Y to hit the enemy. If the enemy has an AC of 14 and you have a +5 to hit, then and 9 and above hits. So you hit if you roll 9-20 on the d20 which is 12/20 = 60% chance to hit)

The general formula for DPR calculation is (average damage) * (chance to hit). The average damage is how damage you do if you hit every round, and the chance to hit is how much you actually hit.

I'll also assume 16 dex at level 1, 18 at lv4 and 20 at lv8 (basically assuming you use point buy and take an ASI whenever possible)

The weapon is longbow with damage dice of 1d8 (average 4.5)

For level 1, it's simple, you attack once per turn, so the DPR is (1d8 + 3) * 0.6 = 7.5 * 0.6 = 4.5

For level 2, you pick the Archery fighting style, so that adds a +2 to hit which is equivalent to a 2/20 = 0.1 increase in hit chance. So now (and onwards) our hit chance will be 0.7
DPR is (1d8 + 3) * 0.7 = 7.5 * 0.7 = 5.25

Now at level 3 the first Hunter feature you picked comes in. When the condition for using it isn't met, the DPR is still that for level 2, but when you can make the second attack, the DPR will be 10.5 (twice the DPR for level 2)

At level 4 you get your first ASI, the DPR for one attack will be (1d8 + 4) * 0.7 = 5.95 and you just double it if you assume you can use Horde Breaker every turn.

At level 5 you get Extra Attack, so two attacks.

Okay so here's a graph with the DPR till level 10, where the higher line is when you assume you can use Horde Breaker every turn.

[image]

(if you use Hunter's Mark or Favored Foe, just add 3.5 or 2.5 to the DPR calculations as shown above)

Now I wouldn't expect damage around the orange line. I wouldn't expect a lot of enemies to stand next to each other all throughout the fight. Horde Breaker is quite situational (in my opinion and from my experience, so yours might not be the same).

Now when you get to level 11 and the Volley feature, things really depend on DM's encounter style. Some DMs spread out the enemies, some DMs just don't have lots of enemies to avoid slowing things down...

Volley's DPR ceiling is arbitrarily high because Tiny creatures don't take space so an arbitrary number can be squeezed inside that radius... but when does that even happen ? If there are 2 enemies in that radius, then it's the same as attacking twice. 3 enemies and 2 of them are 5 feet from each other ? Same as attacking twice and using Horde Breaker. 3 enemies in that radius, none within 5 feet of each other ? Use Volley, but it's the same damage as the previous scenario. 4 enemies in that radius ?

For level 11 and 4 enemies, the damage is (1d8 + 5) * 0.7 * 4 = 26.6

Now all this is "head empty" damage output, so no spells, no advantage/status effects on enemies from spells, etc, but since I don't know what spells you've taken, I'll just explain how advantage affects DPR calculation assuming you cast some sort of status effect spell.

Assuming 0.7 hit chance, when you attack with advantage, you roll 2 dice. The chance of not hitting is 0.3^2 = 0.09 (0.3 to miss on first and 0.3 to miss on second) so hit chance becomes 1 - 0.09 = 0.91.